# Terminal malfunction

Tags: 13.04, command-line

My terminal doesn't open anymore, what should I do? It won't open when I use the hot key and won't work when I click on the program itself, I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 by the way. Please help me!

Comment: Does it print any error messages, if you open it in a term... oh, erm, sorry.

Comment: Workaround: press Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6 to see the virtual consoles, Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to the graphic environment. (I'm not sure that you will be able to run graphical applications through the virtual consoles, though.)

Comment: Start the terminal program from a command line, and post the output. So that we can see whether the problem is in the application. Here are two alternative ways: 1) Enter the virtual console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, login, run `export DISPLAY=:0.0 ; terminal-application-name` 2) add the terminal to the startup applications, and log the output to file by adding `1 > logfile.log 2>&1` at the end of the command. At next login, you should see the logfile in your home. Note: I have Xubuntu, don't know what's the default terminal on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to enter a virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Install gnome-terminal with the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`
- Exit the virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

`